# Allow event propagation (bubbling) malsup

Tags: jquery, google-tag-manager, jquery-forms-plugin

I'm using Google Tag Manager tracking form submissions. Is there any way with [malsup jquery form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) to allow the event propagation? When it prevents the event from bubbling Tag Manager is not able to track the form submission. I have no extra need, just the basic example + allowing the event to propagate to Tag Manager.

```
    // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
        $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
            alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
        }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin doesn't actually submit a form. You'll need to add a bit of code to the .ajaxForm callback function to cause an event in GTM. Add the following line to your callback:

```
dataLayer.push({'event': 'my_event_name'});
```

This will push an event to your dataLayer. You will also need a rule to detect the event and a Google Analytics event tag to send the event to Google Analytics. Substitute an appropriate event name for my_event_name in the code above.